# How can I use a declaration from an existing rule set in LESS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have an existing rule set with a compound selector like this,

```
.class1 + .class2 { /* declaration block */ }
```

I want to use a particular declaration from this rule set  `prop1: value1`

In my LESS is there a way to get the effect of `(.class1+.class2).prop1` ?

I do not want to duplicate prop1 in the new class but use the declaration from `.class1 + .class2`

I have tried the following without success,

```
(.class1+.class2).prop1
.class1+.class2.prop1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this except by moving that declaration to its own mixin, then referencing said mixin in both `.class1 + class2` and anywhere else you want to reference this declaration:

```
.prop1() {
    prop1: value1;
}

.class1 + .class2 {
    .prop1;
}

.class3 {
    .prop1;
}
```

On a side note: in standard selector syntax, "compound selector" refers specifically to a sequence of simple selectors — what you have is a complex selector consisting of two compound selectors, `.class1` and `.class2`, separated by a `+` combinator. Just a minor nitpick, but will go a long way toward understanding the more sophisticated selectors that will be introduced in future standards. There is no notation in either standard CSS or LESS that will allow you to reference a style declaration based on a selector, as many rulesets can have the same selector and styles can cascade differently on a per-element basis.

Comment: I noticed something interesting that made me realize that LESS is just a pre-processor.

Comment: newbie on this site! did not know I have only 5 minutes to complete comment! If a class is defined in multiples places (can happen if different .less files are imported) and then if it is used as a mixin then all the declarations show up including the ones defined *after* the use of the mixin. Seems like it makes more than 1 pass. I was expecting to see only those declarations that had been defined until the point where the mixin was used. Also it just inserts all the declarations i.e. if a property was defined once and again later then both the declarations were output in the same order.